# how to get every fourth element avector R?

Tags: r

If I have this:

```
dat=c("2000", "2050", "2100", "2150", "2200", "2250", "2000", "2350", "2400", "2450")
```

I can replace using

```
la=gsub("2000", "", dat)
```

What I need is to keep every fourth element, to be

```
c("", "", "", "2150", "", "", "", "2350", "", "")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
dat[-seq(4, length(dat), by=4)] <- ""
```

Gives

```
> dat
 [1] ""     ""     ""     "2150" ""     ""     ""     "2350" ""     ""
```

`seq(4, length(dat), by=4)` gives you the sequence `(4, 8, ...)` and
`-` negates it

Answer (score 4):

Using `ifelse`

```
ifelse(seq_along(dat)%%4 == 0, dat, "")
 [1] ""     ""     ""     "2150" ""     ""     ""     "2350" ""     ""
```

Answer (score 4):

We're in the area of personal preference;
Mine would be

```
dat[seq_along(dat) %% 4 !=0] <- ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
> dat[replace(rep(TRUE, 4), 4, FALSE)] <- ""

> dat
 [1] ""     ""     ""     "2150" ""     ""     ""     "2350" ""     ""
```